# HTML5shiv not working on IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I'm trying to make "UberMenu" plugin for Wordpress compatible with Internet Explorer 8 by following [this tutorial](http://sevenspark.com/diagnosis/html5-nav-element-menu-displayed-as-unstyled-list?term_ref=880)

I tried to use HTML shim and  element instead of  too but my menu still shows as an unordered, unstyled list on IE8.

My website: [Cicero gestionale studio legale](https://www.versari.it/)

```
!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script src="https://www.versari.it/wp-content/themes/maximus/css/html5shiv.js"></script>

<![endif]-->
```

Can you gently help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: [html5shiv not working in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15891535).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5shiv not working in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891535/html5shiv-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: For basic styling, check this answer of mine: [Supporting IE8 with HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38029337/2827823)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question does seem like a possible duplicate, as suggested in the comments, so I think you should check the other answers first.

Recently, I encountered a similar problem while designing a navigation menu for my website. The menu just won't style in IE 8 with HTML5shiv. What worked for me is just adding a `<body>` tag to the main HTML and then it displayed fine.

So I suggest:

1. Check to see if you have `<body>` and `</body>` tags enclosing your code.
2. See if there is a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the first line.
3. Make sure your `HTML5shiv` script element is at the `head` section.

Also, the `!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->` of your code needs to include an open bracket at the beginning: `<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->`