# Supporting IE8 with HTML5

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've noticed that some websites I worked on years ago are now broken in IE8. It took a while to figure out but I see the file — http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js — that I've always used is now offline.

I don't often build websites these days so I'm a little out of touch. But have devs basically abandoned this browser now? or is there some other alternative file to fix it?

Comment: Yes, we've abandoned it. Unless your analytics says there are a lot of u users still using it, don't worry about supporting it.

Comment: HTML5Shiv is now hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv). But actually, market share of IE8 is negligible, so the only case when HTML5Shiv may still be needed is using in conjunction with a universal simplified [semantics-based stylesheet](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/) for old IE versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use HTML5 elements in IE8, for basic styling, you only need this

CSS

```
article,aside,dialog,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,
main,nav,section,details,mark,menu,summary { display:block; }
```

JS (run on load)

```
(function(d) {
  var e = 'article aside details figcaption figure footer header main mark menu nav section summary'.split(' '),i=e.length;
  while(i--) { d.createElement(e[i]); }
})(document);
```

---

*Side note:*

For IE9 one actually need this (if not use any library, as they normally does this already)

CSS

```
main { display:block; }
```